# Problem when trying to overwrite the row color with a custom class with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply custom colors on a bootstrap vue table.

I'd like to apply a custom color to the row with the inactive class.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far but without any success (this code is within a VueJS component):

```
<style scoped>
    table tbody tr td {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .inactive{
        background: #038a0a !important;
    }
</style>
```

Thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its working fine when i try it with Bootstrap

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
})
```

```css
<style scoped>
    table tbody tr td {
        padding: 120px;
        background-color:"red"
    }
    .inactive{
        background: #038a0a !important;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="inactive">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's still not working for me.. Maybe it's because my table is within a div with the class "panel panel-default" ?